# Picking points some distance $r$ from a line segment?

Tags: geometry

How do I pick a point some precise distance $r$ from a line segment, i.e. somewhere along a "capped" cylinder about the line, where the line is defined by two points, $p_1$ and $p_2$?  What if I wanted to restrict this to a non-capped "normal" cylinder?

Comment: The set of points distance $r$ from a line segment is going to form a cylinder. So it seems you are asking to find the equation of a cylinder given an equation of a line?

Comment: @WouterZeldenthuis Yes, that's correct - and how to pick random points on this cylinder, including the top and bottom regions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you are working in $\mathbb R^3$, WLOG (using translation and rotation), let $P_1 = (0, 0, 0)$ and $P_2 = (0, 0, p)$.
Then the line segment is given by $(0, 0, tp)$ for $t \in  [0, 1]$.

The cylinder would be given by $(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, tp)$ for $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$
and the "caps" at both ends by the two sets of equations:
$ [x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2] \wedge [z < 0] \quad $ and
$ \quad [x^2 + y^2 + (z-p)^2 = r^2] \wedge [z > p]$.

Not sure if this is exactly what you wanted, but this may get you started.

Comment: Now you can pick a first random to determine whether the point is on the first end, the cylinder, or the other, based on the ratio of areas: $\pi r^2:2 \pi rh : \pi r^2$, then pick a point in that region.  Make sure you pick the points with density $\sqrt r$ so you don't have too many near the center

Comment: @Macavity Where I get in trouble is the case where the cylinder is tilted at some angle, e.g. P1 = {4,5,6} and P2 = {6,1,7}...

Comment: You could translate $P_1$ to the origin first and use the same translation on $P_2$ to get $(2, -4, 1)$ there.  Finding the right rotation is harder, but doable - search for Wahba's problem, in this case the application is quite easy. BTW, assuming the capped ends are hemispheres, the area ratios will be $r: h: r$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scheme, you need to work the details. I assume you are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

You need to find a basis for $\{p_2-p_1\}^\bot$. Let $L = \|p_2-p_1\|_2$. One way is to start with $h_1 = \frac{p_2-p_1}{L}$, the basis vectors $e_k$, and apply Gram Schmidt orthogonalization to get $h_2, h_3$ that form an orthonormal set.

The ends have areas $A_e = \pi r^2$, the side has area $A_s = 2 \pi r L$. The total area  $A=2 A_e + A_s$.

Define
$$x_{i,e}(\rho, \theta) = p_i+\sqrt{\rho}(\cos \theta h_2 + \sin \theta h_3)$$
$$x_s(\lambda, \theta) = p_1 + \lambda h_1+r(\cos \theta h_2 + \sin \theta h_3)$$
The function $x_{i,e}$ maps $[0,r]\times[0,2 \pi]$ into the ends, and $x_s$ maps $[0,L]\times[0,2 \pi]$ into the side. The $\sqrt{\rho}$ in $x_{i,e}$ will keep the distribution uniform (basically reflects the '$r^2$' in the area formula).

Now let $\omega \in [0,1]^3$, and define $x(\omega) = \begin{cases} x_{1,e}(\omega_2 r, 2 \pi \omega_3) & \omega_1 \in [0,\frac{A_e}{A}) \\ x_{2,e}(\omega_2 r, 2 \pi \omega_3) & \omega_1 \in [1-\frac{A_e}{A},1] \\ x_{s}(\omega_2L, 2 \pi \omega_3) & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

$\omega_1$ selects the top, bottom or side, and the other two variables select a point on the corresponding surface.
To select a point uniformly, choose $\omega \in [0,1]^3$ uniformly and use the point $x(\omega)$.